# Looking for free tool or template to generate an online user's guide for web-based system

Tags: eclipse, web-applications, manual, manuals

I am looking for a a free template or tool to help creating an online user's guide (manual) for a web-based system. I have been searching on the web for hours and just found some expensive commercial solutions with too many functionalities.

I am trying to create something like http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp. Just checked that eclipse has one but seems that can be used just on eclipse RCP projects.

Do you know any free tool or template for this task? I would really appreciate any help.

Many thanks,
Thiago

Answer (score 1):

[Docbook](http://www.docbook.org/) good but there's a learning curve...

Answer (score 0):

Why not use an [open source wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_free_and_open_source_software_packages)?  Or something like [Doxygen](http://doxygen.org) will auto-generate help like documentation from source code.

Comment: I thought about using a wiki but would like to something more similar to a chm help style.

Comment: Doxygen is to create code documentation - already done that with javadoc as since as I am using Java. Thanks for your response.